# LocalStorage message passing issue - nearly works

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, message-passing

I have been trying for the last two days to get this to work and as a last resort I am asking here. I have looked on all of the related posts on StackOverflow that are relating to message passing, some blogs and of course Google's message passing page.

The APP that I have built will look for a link in a page containing something and replace the start of it. For example, will look for 'google.com' in a url and replace the start with 'ask.com'.

The issue I am having is that I want to store this variable in a localstorage variable which seems to happen. However when the page is refreshed the new url passed is not being used. I have stripped out a little of the clutter to make a simplified version to make it easier to debug. Please please help! Will have no hair left soon!

`localStorage["talktest1"]` contains a url that should change to a new one passed from the popup.js. Then when the replacement script is loaded next it should use the new `talktest1` variable, however it continues to use the old 'www.google.co.uk' variable.

`Manifest.js`:

```js
{
  "name": "Talk Talk",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Tests stuff.",  
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
    "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js","js/bg.js"]
  },
    "icons": { "16": "img/icon16.png",
               "48": "img/icon48.png",
               "128": "img/icon128.png" },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js","js/bg.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

`popup.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().alert_this();

    $('.link_change').click(function() { // when a link is clicked - url is grabbed from a 'href'

        chrome.extension.sendRequest({localstorage: "http://www.something.com"}, function(response) {
            var email = response.value;
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().alert_this();
        });     

        return false;
    });


});
```

`bg.js`:

```
if(!talktest1){
    var talktest1;
}
if(!localStorage["talktest1"]){
    localStorage["talktest1"] = "http://www.google.co.uk";
}

talktest1 = localStorage["talktest1"];


chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {       
        localStorage["talktest1"] = request.localstorage;
        talktest1 = request.localstorage;
        sendResponse({value: localStorage.talktest1});
    }
);

function alert_this(){
    alert("localstore|" + localStorage["talktest1"]);
    alert("talktest1|" + talktest1);
}


$("a[href*='google.com']").each(function(){ 
    this.href = this.href.replace('http://www.ask.com',talktest1);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you set localstorage in popup.html?

Comment: If you set localstorage in popup.html it seems to set the variable only for that domain. It remains unacessable to the rest of the app. So if you use it in a new tab at a different URL it will not retain the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why do you use `bg.js` as a both background page and a content script? It doesn't make any sense. `chrome.extension.onRequest` can't be used in a content script and throws you an error on console. Put `$("a[href*='google.com']")...` part in a different script (something like `content.js`) and update your `manifest.json`.
2. You haven't set up a `manifest_version` and the default is 1 where `background` setting wasn't available ([source](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html)), there was only a `background_page`.
3. `$('.link_change').click` in `popup.js` reacts only on links inside the popup being clicked, not links from the site. Is that what you intended? Popup lives its own life, it doesn't have any idea about currently open website.
4. I believe you can't display an `alert()` from a background page. Does your `alert_this()` function even work?
5. Are there any errors in popup or on the bg page? Have you debugged it? You should try putting a breakpoint in `onRequest` listener function (bg.js) and see what happens there (is `request.localstorage`, ok? Are values being set correctly?). To debug a background page please use `Inspect active views` option under your extension on the chrome extensions page.

Comment: What I am trying to do is:

When the extension is installed it uses a default url as a replacement. Then according to a link clicked on in the popup.html it should change the replacement url for the extension. So then in any pages opened after or reloaded will automatically use this new url. I have been trying to use localSorage. However the popup.html doesnt want to talk to anything but background.html, this doesnt seem to have access to the localStorage for some reason, I am confused. 

I have done what you have said. Added content.js with the $("a[href*='google.com']") in. Please help!!

Comment: I dont actually think I need a background page. The only reason I thought I did was to interact with the localStorage value for the url that will be replaced

Comment: I have tried adding the following to the background.html: function startup(){
 localStorage.setItem("the_prox","http://www.lalala.com");
}

And the following to the content.js however the background still has no localStorage items: chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().startup();

Comment: 1. Whenever user clicks a link in a popup, you should call a function from the background page witch will store a new value in the `localStorage` (ie. `saveSite('http://ask.com/')`). 2. At the begining of the content script, call background function that retrieves the value from the localStorage (ie. `getSite()`). Don't use `localStorage` variable in the popup or in the content script directly. Always call the background page to get the value and you'll be fine.